# Gerrit: Is there a setting to ignore whitespace changes in the diff, for all users?

Tags: diff, whitespace, gerrit

I've migrated over 200 Python files from Python 2 to Python 3.

Almost every file has white space changes.  Those changes make it harder to spot the code changes.

I can click the gear icon and and make the view of the white space change disappear, per file.

Is there a way I can set that preference on all 200 files in one shot?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can set this by two ways:

1. At the main menu dropdown by your name in the top right hand corner

***Settings*** > ***Diff Preferences*** > ***Ignore Whitespace*** > ***SAVE CHANGES***

2. At the change diff page

***Diff Preferences*** > ***Ignore Whitespace*** > ***SAVE***

Find the (1) and the (2) at the up/right side of the Gerrit UI:

[image]

Comment: How I find the main menu?  The only "menu" I found was by clicking on the gear icon. Setting the preference there only it applies it to that one file.

Comment: I added more info to the answer.

Comment: I have Gerrit version v2.13.8-4-gb79a18cfff-dirty.  My UI looks very different from yours.  I only have one gear icon.  It gives me the the choice of setting preference on ONE file for one viewing, or permanently.

Comment: The 2.13 is an old version, I really don't remember how it was at this point. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks much for the info.

Comment: I assume there is a way to change the default on a Gerrit server installation, e.g. from None to All for ignoring white space. Any pointers on how to do this appreciated!

Comment: I don't think so.